# FPDF gives only lines of code back

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to work with FPDF to export Data from a HTML-Form to a PDF and can't get it to work. I tried the example given in the downloadable tutorial and got only a part of the code back instead of an actual error or even a PDF.

This is the example I used

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

And the output looks like this:

```
AddPage(); $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16); $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!'); $pdf->Output(); ?>
```

I did it exactly as any youtube-tutorials shows it. The file fpdf.php is in the same folder as my php-code and so on. I just don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is php installed on the server?

Comment: Of course. Other scripts are running as expected.

Comment: looks like the php is not even running. file named *.php? called via the webserver?

Comment: It didn't look like it from the output. Is your script named .php? Anything in the web server access logs/error logs for your request?

Comment: Yes it's a php-file and named like one. Logs don't say anything about it. Access granted but that's it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would cause this is if you accidentally typoed `$pdf?>AddPage();` instead of `$pdf->AddPage();` Seems unlikely, but that would produce exactly this output with no errors.